# Mongo aggregation - last record with additional data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, grouping

Lets consider the example:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/
I'l like to include additional fields like price or quantity of last sale. I mean how to include field which is not part of key nor aggregate expression. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is possible to get entire document as an output of $group stage. There's a special variable [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) which is helpful in such situations. So for instance if you want to get last processed document you can use following code:

```
db.sales.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "date": 1 } },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: "$item",
            lastDocument: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
        } 
    }
])
```

Comment: I understand now. Thanks. :)